# Inline confluence user macro

Tags: macros, confluence

How to create a confluence macro with body that produces an inline output? The following macro:

```
## @noparams
<font color="red">$body</font>
```

applied to this text

```
Before macro [macro starts here]macro body[macro ends here] after macro.
```

Will create this HTML code:

```
<p>Before macro </p>
<font color="red">macro body</font>
<p>after macro.</p>
```

How to remove the `<p></p>` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with Confluence. To avoid this, you have to use html output. If the body or your macro contain wiki markup, then you will have to render this by hand. My workaround is as follows:

```
## Use this macro to avoid new lines:
#macro(doNothing)#end
##
## (Do stuff with body in wiki format, if appropriate)
##
## Convert to html and remove paragraph tags:
#set($renderedhtml = "")
#if ($body && ($body.length()>0))
  #set($globalHelper = $action.getHelper())
  #set($renderedhtml = $globalHelper.renderConfluenceMacro("$body").replaceAll("</?[pP]>",""))
#end
##
## (Do stuff with body in html format, if appropriate)
##
## Output text:
$renderedhtml#doNothing()
```

EDIT: You will want to modify the regex if there are p tags in your macro that you want to keep. The regex in the code above will remove ALL p tags.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately my problem is apparently not the new paragraphs in the code generated _by my macro_ but that confluence inserts `</p>` _before_ and `<p>` _after_ my macro, embedding the preceding and the following text into new paragraphs. Can I cancel also these tags?

Comment: That's exactly what the template above does. Try it.

Comment: Can you please explain how to `render by hand`?

Comment: I ended up basing something off of your code. `#set($body = "[link|doc:mypage]")`. Obviously this overwrites body, but the macro isn't supposed to have a body in the first place.

Comment: By render by hand I am just referring to what I do in the script. The idea is actually that you set body to whatever wiki formatting you want to render where it says "(Do stuff with body in wiki format, if appropriate)", so your usage fits perfectly with my intent.

Comment: This is one of several problems with the new Confluence editor after wiki markup was ditched in Confluence V4 [which has since been resolved](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-10790) as of Confluence 5.4.